# Count instances in constructor

Tags: java, increment

In my EMR Class, I am trying increment the patient counter data field after my constructor with 2 variables. I am also trying to increment the patient counter datafield after my construct with 5 variables.

In the Main the end goal is to Create 5 new patient records (which I did) and Print the number of patient records available before and after.

I am pretty sure I have to use `public static long numofpatients` in my EMR class, but don't know where to go from there.

Main code:

```
package studenthealthservices;

public class Studenthealthservices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EMR p1 = new EMR("Colin", "10-22-74", "Strained Ankle", 99, 110, "hurt during football", "ankle brace");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());

        EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan", "9-30-77", "stomach ache", 98, 120, "stress", "Tylenol");
        System.out.println(p2.toString());

        EMR p3 = new EMR("Buster", "3-27-1987", "Broken ankle", 99, 113, "Scott Cousins", "None");
        System.out.println(p3.toString());

        EMR P4 = new EMR("Frank The Tank", "4/1/89");

        EMR p5 = new EMR("Merton Hanks", "03-12-1968");
    }
}
```

EMR class code:

```
package studenthealthservices;

public class EMR {
    private String name;
    private String dob;
    private String rfv;
    private double bodyt;
    private double hr;
    private String diag;
    private String pmeds;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public EMR(String name, String dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public EMR(String name, String dob, String rfv, double bodyt, double hr, String diag, String pmeds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.rfv = rfv;
        this.bodyt = bodyt;
        this.hr = hr;
        this.diag = diag;
        this.pmeds = pmeds;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getRfv() {
        return rfv;
    }

    public void setRfv(String rfv) {
        this.rfv = rfv;
    }

    public double getBodyt() {
        return bodyt;
    }

    public void setBodyt(double bodyt) {
        this.bodyt = bodyt;
    }

    public double getHr() {
        return hr;
    }

    public void setHr(double hr) {
        this.hr = hr;
    }

    public String getDiag() {
        return diag;
    }

    public void setDiag(String diag) {
        this.diag = diag;
    }

    public String getPmeds() {
        return pmeds;
    }

    public void setPmeds(String pmeds) {
        this.pmeds = pmeds;
    }

    public void redFlags() {
        String help = "get help!";
        if (bodyt >= 97.3 && bodyt <= 99.1)
            this.bodyt = bodyt;
        if (hr >= 60 && hr <= 100)
            this.hr = hr;
        else {
            System.out.printf(help);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nname : " + this.name
            + "\nDate of Birth: " + this.dob
            + "\nReason for visit: " + this.rfv
            + "\nBody Temperature: " + this.bodyt
            + "\nHeart Rate " + this.hr
            + "\nDiagnosis: " + this.diag
            + "\nPrescribed Meds " + this.pmeds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not track number of patients in the class that initializes objects of the EMR class, which in your case, would be the Studenthealthservices class?

Comment: you are trying to have a counter to keep track of how many EMR's have been created? but you need the counter in your EMR class not the one creating it ?

Comment: numofpatients++ in each EMR constructor?

Answer (score 1):

see here (simplified your class):

```
package studenthealthservices;

public class EMR 
{
   private static /*volatile*/ long numofpatients; // when using different threads, volatile is needed.

   private String name;
   private String dob;

   public EMR(String name, String dob) {
      numofpatients++; //increment here          
      this.name = name;
      this.dob = dob;
   }

   public EMR(String name, String dob, String rfv, double bodyt, double hr, String diag, String pmeds) {
       numofpatients++; //increment here           
       this.name = name;
       this.dob = dob;
       //simplified
   }

   public String getDob() {
       return dob;
   }

   public void setDob(String dob) {
       this.dob = dob;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "simplified";
   }

   public static long getInstanceCount()
   {
       return numofpatients;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid incrementing a `static` variable in the constructor, and instead push that responsibility into the `StudentHealthServices` class, like this:

```
public class StudentHealthServices {
    private int numOfPatients;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentHealthServices services = new StudentHealthServices();
        EMR p1 = new EMR("Colin", "10-22-74", "Strained Ankle", 99, 110, "hurt during football", "ankle brace");
        services.add(p1);

        EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan", "9-30-77", "stomach ache", 98, 120, "stress", "Tylenol");
        services.add(p2);

        EMR p3 = new EMR("Buster", "3-27-1987", "Broken ankle", 99, 113, "Scott Cousins", "None");
        services.add(p3);

        EMR p4 = new EMR("Frank The Tank", "4/1/89");
        services.add(p4);

        EMR p5 = new EMR("Merton Hanks", "03-12-1968");
        services.add(p5);
    }

    private void add(EMR emr) {
        // maybe you want to store the patients in a list here?
        System.out.println(emr);
        System.out.println("there are now " + ++numOfPatients + " patients");
    }
}
```